# Haskell: What is the definition for '{' '}' and ','?

Tags: haskell

I was trying lo look up the definition for `{` and `}` and `,` as used in the following for example, but I could not find them. Are these functions ?

```
data Person = Person { 
  pID :: Int, 
  pName :: String 
} deriving (Show)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. These are not functions, but part of a datatype declaration using the record syntax. See [4.2 User-Defined Datatypes](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-700004.2.1) in Haskell Report for details.

Comment: thank you, so just to confirm: the , is not the same as the one for tuples ? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Tuple.html#t:-40--44--44--41-

Comment: It is the same character (the comma `,`) but no, it is not part of the same construct.  Curiously, you can think of them as the same _concept_ - a tuple and a record with multiple fields are just two different [product types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type).  The tuple, `(,)` is a data constructor that lacks field names and has special syntax by virtue of being built into the language.  `Person` is a data constructor with explicit field name but otherwise isomorphic (of identical utility) to tuple type `(Int, String)`.